# Why the default theme in Kendo-UI for Angular doesn't change the accent color?

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to change the accent color for an Angular application developed with Kendo-UI. After a bit of searching I managed to understand what I have to change, and that is the `$accent` variable from the default value `#ff6358` to any color you want.

---

[This link](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/theme-default/customization/) provides some help.

Also, the official documentation:

### Customization

To customize the Default Theme in one swoop, use the colors which are defined in the `scss/_variables.scss` file. Any change you make to the content of this file is propagated to every component.

To style a specific component, apply the variables which are used in its specific `.scss` file.

After you build the theme by running the `npm run build` command, the complete theme that you can use in your project will be available in the `dist/all.css` file.

---

I did all those things and when I check my `all.css` file, it's the same one than before. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sass, the order of the declarations matters. You need to declare the new value of $accent first, and import Kendo's styles later, so they use the correct value.

```
$accent: #666666;
@import "~@progress/kendo-theme-default/scss/all";
```

(Less, on the other hand, is lazily evaluated and it's the last declaration that counts.)

More on Sass and overriding here: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/sass-default

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I managed to find [similar documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/custom-themes/#toc-using-the-build-process-of-the-themes) for the Kendo-UI, but still I haven't managed to make it work. @GaloisGirl

Comment: I have it working, but on Kendo for jQuery. If the accent color is the only variable you want to change, you may use the [Kendo Theme Builder](https://themebuilder.telerik.com/) . Otherwise, we'll need more info on what you're exactly doing to be able to help.

Comment: Thank you! It was pretty straightforward after all :)

Comment: it takes a long time to reload with `ng serve` though, when testing

Comment: @xinthose see https://github.com/telerik/kendo-themes/issues/423